# confluent control-center directory not found in confluent-5.5.3

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-control-center

I have downloaded the confluent-community-5.5.3-2.12.tar
I am unable to see the /etc/confluent-control-center directory?
Is it unavailable in community edition? If so, what other options do I have?

Thanks.

Comment: Does [this](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/control-center/installation/troubleshooting.html) help?

Comment: @Shag, i am not able to see any directory as control-center. No properties files as well. However the latest 6.0.1 does contain everything related to control-center.